# How to display ndarray images inline during loop in IPython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

The following code

```
%matplotlib inline

for i in range(0, 5):
    index = np.random.choice(len(dataset))
    print('index:', index)
    image = dataset[index, :, :]
    print('image shape:', np.shape(image))
    plt.imshow(image)
```

display five printouts and one single image at the end in `jupyter notebook`.

Is it possible, to display images on each loop iteration?

I was able to do this with image files with

```
for fullname in fullnames:
  print('fullname:', fullname)
  display(Image(filename=fullname))
```

Is it possible to do the same with ndarrays?

**UPDATE**

Writing

```
for i in range(0, 5):
   ...
   plt.figure()
   plt.imshow(image)
```

made it better, but not perfect. Images displayed in multiple, but all are AFTER the text.

Should be interleaved.

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
   ...
   plt.figure()
   plt.imshow(image)
   plt.show()
```

Without `plt.show()` the figures are only rendered and displayed after the cell finishes being executed (i.e., exits the `for` loop). With `plt.show()` you force rendering after every iteration.